# R: create animated gif in rgl with rotation around Z axis

Tags: r, opengl, 3d, image-rotation, rgl

I need to produce an animated gif from a OpenGL visualization package `rgl` in R. The recipe is described [in this link at genomearchitecture.com](http://www.genomearchitecture.com/2014/03/3d-animations-with-r). First we create some 3D cube with our image. It was produced in `plot3D` package via `scatter3D()` commands. Next we invoke a rgl window with it by

```
require(plot3Drgl)
plotrgl()
```

The recipe from the link above sounds as follows (essential part):

```
for (i in 1:90) {
  view3d(userMatrix=rotationMatrix(2*pi * i/90, 1, -1, -1))
  rgl.snapshot(filename=paste("animation/frame-",
    sprintf("%03d", i), ".png", sep=""))
}
```

that is we create 90 rgl snapshots and rotate our object using parameters in `userMatrix=rotationMatrix()` directive. However exactly this directive performs rotation around some specific axis, and the whole rotating animation looks kinky, especially if we have just a 3D geographical map to rotate, like on this image.

[image: cube in rgl]

We do not want this image rotate and go upside down, we just need to rotate it around vertical Z axis. However, every attempt to modify the directive `view3d(userMatrix=rotationMatrix(2*pi * i/90, 1, -1, -1))` changing vector (1,-1,-1) produces the cube with Z axis facing to us with initial position of the angle. 
In the static framework the position of the cube can be intuitively controlled by two polar coordinates via directive

```
plotdev(theta=10,phi=15)
```

It would be good to program the snapshots running theta from 0 to 2 pi with some reasonable phi, but setting theta, phi instead of userMatrix works good only for static image. In rgl window it again produces something not expected, for example, theta=0, phi=0 again aim Z axis towards us. How it is possible to modify the view angle directive to make the cube rotate around its Z axis?

Comment: Did you try the methods in the `spin3d` or `movie3d` help pages?

Comment: I was not aware of spin3d(). But it seems that in combination with play3d it does exactly what is needed even with no parameters!